# Overriding Settings for unit tests in Django doesn't work properly

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-settings

I tried to unit test my Django program and I would like to check several values for a few variables in my `settings.py` file.

In the documentation, the section "[Overriding settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings)" is describing a way to do it. But, despite all my attempts, I miserably fail to make the changes available in the program while the test is running. Here is a summary of what I do on a minimal example:

First, create a new project:

```
$ pyvenv virtualenv
$ cd virtualenv/
$ . bin/activate
(virtualenv) $ pip install django
(virtualenv) $ django-admin startproject myapp
(virtualenv) $ cd myapp/
```

Then, add the following files.

### File `settings.py`

```
...

TEST_VALUE = 'a'
```

### File `tests.py`

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.settings import TEST_VALUE

class CheckSettings(TestCase):

  def test_settings(self):
    self.assertEqual(TEST_VALUE, 'a')

  def test_modified_settings(self):
    with self.settings(TEST_VALUE='b'):
      self.assertEqual(TEST_VALUE, 'b')
```

When I run the tests, I get the following:

```
$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_modified_settings (myapp.tests.CheckSettings)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/virtualenv/myapp/tests.py", line 12, in test_modified_settings
    self.assertEqual(TEST_VALUE, 'b')
AssertionError: 'a' != 'b'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

As you may have noticed, the original value of `TEST_VALUE` is `'a'`, and I try to modify it through the `self.settings(TEST_VALUE='b')`... but, without success.

You may try it through an empty project (Django is 1.6.5).

So, what am I missing to get it work properly ?

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe you have to have to access the setting via `settings` -- e.g. `from testing_settings import settings`, and then use `settings.TEST_VALUE` in your assert. Changing a value you already imported seems a bit too magical.

Comment: Or `from django.conf import settings`, actually.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: Damn, you are right !!! Just to sum up, I was taking the variables from the `settings.py` file through a `from myapp.settings import TEST_VALUE`, but in fact I should have done it like `from django.conf import settings` and then `settings.TEST_VALUE`... Thanks for the hint ! It helped a lot.

Comment: Also, note that there's a `modify_settings()` decorator. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.modify_settings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to sum up what I understood from the comment from Ismail Badawi, in fact, I was not calling properly the variable from the `settings.py` because I was using `from myapp.settings import TEST_VALUE`, where I should have call it using `from django.conf import settings` and then `settings.TEST_VALUE`.

So, here is a proper `tests.py` file:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings

class CheckSettings(TestCase):

  def test_settings(self):
    self.assertEqual(settings.TEST_VALUE, 'a')

  def test_modified_settings(self):
    with self.settings(TEST_VALUE='b'):
      self.assertEqual(settings.TEST_VALUE, 'b')
```

And, here is the result of `./manage.py test`:

```
$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

So, the lesson of this little story is to always get your settings values from `django.conf` and not from `myapp.settings` when you use it.

Note also that if you are using a cache, some values of your `settings.py` may be stored in it and could be masked by their cached value. For that, the documentation of Django on "[Overriding settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings)" gives a hint to solve this kind of problem:

> When overriding settings, make sure to handle the cases in which your app’s code uses a cache or similar feature that retains state even if the setting is changed. Django provides the `django.test.signals.setting_changed` signal that lets you register callbacks to clean up and otherwise reset state when settings are changed.

Thought, the way to implement it for real is not given. It could be a good question to ask next...

Comment: Also, if you use some of those settings at module level (like, storing them in some globals for faster lookup/less cumbersome access), you must reload them based on the settings_changed signal. Not useful here, but thought it would be worth adding it as it is closely related.

Comment: @spectras: Yes, you are right to mention it, I'll make a note about that.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the @override_settings decorator. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.utils.override_settings